# How to create all permutations starting from a list of words

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, multidimensional-array

I have a list of 10 words and need to create an array containing all the different permutations from these words, ie [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,4,3],[1,4,2,3],...].

I managed to make it work through Javascript but I am really struggling with VBA.

```
function perm(xs) {
  let ret = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < xs.length; i = i + 1) {
    let rest = perm(xs.slice(0, i).concat(xs.slice(i + 1)));

    if (!rest.length) {
      ret.push([xs[i]])
    } else {
      for (let j = 0; j < rest.length; j = j + 1) {
        ret.push([xs[i]].concat(rest[j]))
      }
    }
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to write any VBA Code so far ?

Comment: Is 10 the maximum of words and do you always pick exactly 4? Are repetitions of words allowed? eg [1,1,1,1]?

Comment: Your question shows an array or arrays.  Is that a requirement?  Would a two dimensional array with 4 columns and one row per permutation be acceptable?

Comment: the words will always be 10 and I need all 10 words to be part of all the permutations. Order matters - ie (only 4 elements for ease of writing) so Word1, Word2, Word3, Word4 has to be one array but Word2, Word1, Word3, Word4 has to be another combination

Comment: @TonyDallimore yes two dimensional arrays are fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pᴇʜ and Tragamor both interpret your question as a request for all permutations of four words.  I interpret your question as a request for all permutations of ten words.  Their answers match their interpretation.  This answer matches my interpretation although it should return all permutations of any number of words.  I have fully tested my routine at creating all permutations of from three to nine words.  For ten or more words my test routine takes too long to be viable.  Since my routine works for up to and including nine words, I assume it works for larger numbers.

Both Pᴇʜ and Tragamor have used recursion.  I consider recursion to be a very useful technique but for VBA, if not for other languages, it is a slow technique.  I decided against recursion.

With my technique, the Permutation routine has two parameters: the array, Words, (containing the ten words) and the array Permutations (in which the 3,628,800 permutations are returned).  The routine has an array, PermCrnt, containing the indices of the ten words.  If the lower bound of Words is 0, the initial value of PermCrnt is:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

The main loop of the Permutation routine uses PermCrnt’s indices to output the current permutation to array Permutations and then resets PermCrnt to the next sequence.  This loop continues until array Permutations is full.

The code that resets PermCrnt looks from the right for two indices that are not in ascending sequence.  Those indices and all to the right are removed from PermCrnt.  The leftmost indice removed is replaced by the next in sequence.  The remaining indices are placed in ascending sequence.  This gives:

```
                      First pair not in ascending sequence. Remove that
PermCrnt              pair and all to their right and re-sequence them.
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9   “8 9”
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 9 8   “7 9”
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 8 7 9   “7 9”
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 8 9 7   “8 9”
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 9 7 8   “7 8”
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 9 8 7   “6 9”
0 1 2 3 4 5 7 6 8 9   “8 9”
0 1 2 3 4 5 7 6 9 8
```

As can be seen, this simple algorithm cycles through all possible permutation until:

```
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

For ten words, my routine takes around 12 seconds to generate the 3,628,800 permutations.

My routine, and its test is below.  Note: because of the way I have tested `PermWords`, it was convenient for `Words` to be a Variant.  You may wish to change to an array of strings.

```
Option Explicit
Sub CallPermutations()

  Dim ColOutCrnt As Long
  Dim Duration As Single
  Dim InxPerm As Long
  Dim InxWord As Long
  Dim Match As Boolean
  Dim MultiWords As Variant
  Dim NumWords As Long
  Dim NumPerms As Long
  Dim Permutations() As String
  Dim RowOutCrnt1 As Long
  Dim RowOutCrnt2 As Long
  Dim RowOutMax As Long
  Dim TimeStart As Single
  Dim Words As Variant

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  MultiWords = VBA.Array(VBA.Array("apple", "bear", "cat"), _
                         VBA.Array("apple", "bear", "cat", "dog"), _
                         VBA.Array("apple", "bear", "cat", "dog", "egg"), _
                         VBA.Array("apple", "bear", "cat", "dog", "egg", "fast"), _
                         VBA.Array("apple", "bear", "cat", "dog", "egg", "fast", _
                                   "game"), _
                         VBA.Array("apple", "bear", "cat", "dog", "egg", "fast", _
                                   "game", "house"), _
                         VBA.Array("apple", "bear", "cat", "dog", "egg", "fast", _
                                   "game", "house", "island"), _
                         VBA.Array("apple", "bear", "cat", "dog", "egg", "fast", _
                                   "game", "house", "island", "joy"))

  For Each Words In MultiWords

    TimeStart = Timer
    Call PermWords(Words, Permutations)
    Duration = Timer - TimeStart

    NumWords = UBound(Words) - LBound(Words) + 1
    NumPerms = UBound(Permutations, 1) - LBound(Permutations, 1) + 1

    Debug.Print "Generating " & PadL(NumPerms, 7) & _
                " permutations of " & PadL(NumWords, 2) & _
                " words took " & PadL(Format(Duration, "#,##0.000"), 9) & " seconds"

    If NumWords < 9 Then

     TimeStart = Timer
      For RowOutCrnt1 = LBound(Permutations, 1) To UBound(Permutations, 1) - 1
        For RowOutCrnt2 = RowOutCrnt1 + 1 To UBound(Permutations, 1)
          Match = True
          For ColOutCrnt = 1 To NumWords
            If Permutations(RowOutCrnt1, ColOutCrnt) <> _
               Permutations(RowOutCrnt2, ColOutCrnt) Then
              Match = False
              Exit For
            End If
          Next
          If Match Then
            Debug.Print
            Debug.Print "Row " & RowOutCrnt1 & " = " & "Row " & RowOutCrnt2
            Debug.Assert False
          Else
          End If
        Next
      Next

      Duration = Timer - TimeStart

      Debug.Print "Testing    " & PadL(NumPerms, 7) & _
                  " permutations of " & PadL(NumWords, 2) & _
                  " words took " & PadL(Format(Duration, "#,##0.000"), 9) & " seconds"
    End If

    DoEvents
  Next

End Sub
Sub PermWords(ByRef Words As Variant, ByRef Permutations() As String)

  ' On entry Words is a list of words created by Array, VBA.Array or
  ' by code that emulated Array or VBA.Array.
  ' On exit, Permutations will contain one row permutation of the words.

  ' Note: Array creates an array with a lower bound of zero or one depending
  ' on the Option Base statement while VBA.Array creates an array with a
  ' lower bound that is always zero.

  ' Permutations will be redim'ed as a two-dimensional array.  The first
  ' dimension will have bounds of one to number-of-permutations.  The second
  ' dimension will have bounds to match those of Words.

  ' If Words contains "one", "two" and "three", Permutations will contain:
  '   "one"   "two"   "three"
  '   "one"   "three" "two"
  '   "two"   "one"   "three"
  '   "two"   "three" "one"
  '   "three" "one"   "two"
  '   "three" "two"   "one"

  Dim InxPermCrnt As Long
  Dim InxToPlaceCrnt As Long
  Dim InxToPlaceMax As Long
  Dim InxToPlaceNext As Long
  Dim InxWord As Long
  Dim ValueNext As Long
  Dim NumPerms As Long
  Dim NumWords As Long
  Dim PermCrnt() As Long
  Dim RowPerms As Long
  Dim ToPlace() As Long

  ' Calculate number of words and number of permutations
  NumWords = UBound(Words) - LBound(Words) + 1
  NumPerms = Factorial(NumWords)

  ' Redim arrays to required size
  ReDim PermCrnt(LBound(Words) To UBound(Words))
  ReDim Permutations(1 To NumPerms, LBound(Words) To UBound(Words))
  ReDim ToPlace(1 To NumWords)

  RowPerms = 1    ' First row in Permutations

  ' Create initial sequence of words
  For InxWord = LBound(Words) To UBound(Words)
    PermCrnt(InxWord) = InxWord
  Next

  ' Loop until Permutations() is full
  Do While True
    ' Output current permutation to Permutations
    For InxPermCrnt = LBound(PermCrnt) To UBound(PermCrnt)
      InxWord = PermCrnt(InxPermCrnt)
      Permutations(RowPerms, InxPermCrnt) = Words(InxWord)
    Next
    RowPerms = RowPerms + 1
    If RowPerms > UBound(Permutations, 1) Then
      ' All permutations generated
      Exit Sub
    End If
    ' Generate next sequence
    ' Find first pair from right not in ascending sequence
    ' Copy this pair, and all to its right, to ToPlace()
    InxToPlaceMax = 1
    ToPlace(InxToPlaceMax) = PermCrnt(UBound(PermCrnt))
    For InxPermCrnt = UBound(PermCrnt) - 1 To LBound(PermCrnt) Step -1
      InxToPlaceMax = InxToPlaceMax + 1
      ToPlace(InxToPlaceMax) = PermCrnt(InxPermCrnt)
      If PermCrnt(InxPermCrnt) < PermCrnt(InxPermCrnt + 1) Then
        Exit For
      End If
    Next
    ' Elements InxPermCrnt to UBound(PermCrnt) of PermCrnt are to be
    ' resequenced.  PermCrnt(InxPermCrnt) will reference the next to place word
    ' in sequence.  Remaining elements will be the values from ToPlace() in
    ' ascending sequence.
    ' Find next value above value in PermCrnt(InxPermCrnt)
    ValueNext = -1
    InxToPlaceNext = -1
    For InxToPlaceCrnt = 1 To InxToPlaceMax
      If PermCrnt(InxPermCrnt) < ToPlace(InxToPlaceCrnt) Then
        ' ToPlace(InxToPlaceCrnt) is greater than PermCrnt(InxPermCrnt). It will
        ' be the next in sequence unless there is PermCrnt(X) such that
        ' PermCrnt(InxPermCrnt) < PermCrnt(X) < ToPlace(InxToPlaceCrnt)
        If InxToPlaceNext = -1 Then
          ' This is the first ToPlace entry found that is greater than
          ' PermCrnt(InxPermCrnt)
          ValueNext = ToPlace(InxToPlaceCrnt)
          InxToPlaceNext = InxToPlaceCrnt
        Else
          ' This is not the first ToPlace value greater than PermCrnt(InxPermCrnt)
          If ValueNext > ToPlace(InxToPlaceCrnt) Then
            ValueNext = ToPlace(InxToPlaceCrnt)
            InxToPlaceNext = InxToPlaceCrnt
          End If
        End If
      End If
    Next
    ' If stop here, next value in sequence not found
    Debug.Assert ValueNext <> PermCrnt(InxPermCrnt)
    ' Place next value in PermCrnt() and remove from ToPlace()
    PermCrnt(InxPermCrnt) = ValueNext
    ToPlace(InxToPlaceNext) = ToPlace(InxToPlaceMax)
    InxToPlaceMax = InxToPlaceMax - 1
    ' Move remaining values in ToPlace() to PermCrnt() in ascending sequence
    Do While InxToPlaceMax > 0
      InxPermCrnt = InxPermCrnt + 1  ' Next position within PermCrnt
      ' Find next value to place
      ValueNext = ToPlace(1)
      InxToPlaceNext = 1
      For InxToPlaceCrnt = 2 To InxToPlaceMax
        If ValueNext > ToPlace(InxToPlaceCrnt) Then
          ValueNext = ToPlace(InxToPlaceCrnt)
          InxToPlaceNext = InxToPlaceCrnt
        End If
      Next
      ' Place next value in PermCrnt() and remove from ToPlace()
      PermCrnt(InxPermCrnt) = ValueNext
      ToPlace(InxToPlaceNext) = ToPlace(InxToPlaceMax)
      InxToPlaceMax = InxToPlaceMax - 1
    Loop  ' until all values in ToPlace() copied to PermCrnt()
  Loop  ' until Permutations() is full

End Sub
Function Factorial(ByVal Num As Long)

  ' Return Fsctorial Num

  '  6Jun19  Coded

  Dim Answer As Long
  Dim I As Long

  Answer = 1
  For I = 1 To Num
    Answer = Answer * I
  Next I
  Factorial = Answer

End Function
Public Function PadL(ByVal Str As String, ByVal PadLen As Long, _
                     Optional ByVal PadChr As String = " ") As String

  ' Pad Str with leading PadChr to give a total length of PadLen
  ' If the length of Str exceeds PadLen, Str will not be truncated

  '   Sep15 Coded
  ' 20Dec15 Added code so overlength strings are not truncated
  ' 10Jun16 Added PadChr so could pad with characters other than space

  If Len(Str) >= PadLen Then
    ' Do not truncate over length strings
    PadL = Str
  Else
    PadL = Right$(String(PadLen, PadChr) & Str, PadLen)
  End If

End Function
Public Function PadR(ByVal Str As String, ByVal PadLen As Long, _
                     Optional ByVal PadChr As String = " ") As String

  ' Pad Str with trailing PadChr to give a total length of PadLen
  ' If the length of Str exceeds PadLen, Str will not be truncated

  '   Nov15 Coded
  ' 15Sep16 Added PadChr so could pad with characters other than space

  If Len(Str) >= PadLen Then
    ' Do not truncate over length strings
    PadR = Str
  Else
    PadR = Left$(Str & String(PadLen, PadChr), PadLen)
  End If

End Function
```

Comment: this is what I was looking for - I just needed all the permutations given an array of 10 words. I have tested and apparently it works, I am going through your code now to understand where these arrays are stored.

Comment: Just for reference as you cite my answer, although it is shown using an array of four words (as is the question), it is adaptable to different array lengths so should be fine for a 10 word array as well.

Comment: @Tragamor.  I was busy with other activities so by the time I had finished my solution you and Pᴇʜ had already posted solutions.  I had a fairly brief check of the solutions you two had posted.  Both aimed at four word permutations and both used recursion.  I did not investigate how easily the solutions could be adapted for ten word permutations but decided a non-recursive solution was sufficiently different to be worth posting as an alternative.

Comment: I like recursion and use it for searching trees of limited depth but I have found recursive routines to be slower than the equivalent non-recursive routines.  I suggest you time your routine in case I am wrong about the slowness of recursion.  If you can beat or offer a near match for my approximately 12 seconds to generate 3,628,800 permutations, you should edit this into your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Without repetition and picking always 4 words

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Permutations()
    Dim Words() As Variant
    Words = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

    Dim p1 As Long, p2 As Long, p3 As Long, p4 As Long
    For p1 = LBound(Words) To UBound(Words)
        For p2 = LBound(Words) To UBound(Words)
            If p2 <> p1 Then
                For p3 = LBound(Words) To UBound(Words)
                    If p3 <> p1 And p3 <> p2 Then
                        For p4 = LBound(Words) To UBound(Words)
                            If p4 <> p1 And p4 <> p2 And p4 <> p3 Then
                                Debug.Print Words(p1); Words(p2); Words(p3); Words(p4)
                            End If
                        Next p4
                    End If
                Next p3
            End If
        Next p2
    Next p1
End Sub
```

Output will be something like

```
 1  2  3  4 
 1  2  3  5 
 1  2  3  6 
 1  2  3  7 
 1  2  3  8 
 1  2  3  9 
 1  2  3  10 
 1  2  4  3 
 1  2  4  5 
 1  2  4  6 
 1  2  4  7 
 1  2  4  8 
…
10  9  8  7
```

Alternatively write a recoursive function.

---

To put all into an array

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub PermutationsToArray()
    Dim Words() As Variant
    Words = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

    Dim WordsCount As Long
    WordsCount = UBound(Words) - LBound(Words) + 1

    Dim OutputCount As Long
    OutputCount = WordsCount * (WordsCount - 1) * (WordsCount - 2) * (WordsCount - 3)

    ReDim OutputArray(0 To OutputCount - 1, 0 To 3) As Variant

    Dim iCount As Long

    Dim p1 As Long, p2 As Long, p3 As Long, p4 As Long
    For p1 = LBound(Words) To UBound(Words)
        For p2 = LBound(Words) To UBound(Words)
            If p2 <> p1 Then
                For p3 = LBound(Words) To UBound(Words)
                    If p3 <> p1 And p3 <> p2 Then
                        For p4 = LBound(Words) To UBound(Words)
                            If p4 <> p1 And p4 <> p2 And p4 <> p3 Then
                                OutputArray(iCount, 0) = Words(p1)
                                OutputArray(iCount, 1) = Words(p2)
                                OutputArray(iCount, 2) = Words(p3)
                                OutputArray(iCount, 3) = Words(p4)
                                iCount = iCount + 1
                            End If
                        Next p4
                    End If
                Next p3
            End If
        Next p2
    Next p1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I find arrays can be a bit awkward to work with, so this recursive algorithm uses a generated character mask as the input for the permutation calculations then copies the relevant items from the source array into the output array.

You could potentially create a 1D array of the character map instead and use that instead of a 2D array if you run into issues with large array data

> Time to calculate and load array for 10 words: 12.62 seconds

```
Dim StartTime As Single

Sub TestMain()
    StartTime = Timer

    Dim InArr() As Variant, OutArr() As Variant
    InArr = Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J")

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, xStr As String

    i = UBound(InArr) - LBound(InArr)
    ReDim OutArr(i, Fact(i + 1) - 1)

    For i = 0 To UBound(InArr) - LBound(InArr)
        xStr = xStr & Chr(i + 65)
    Next i
    Call GetPermutations(InArr, OutArr, xStr)

    Debug.Print Timer - StartTime

    Exit Sub

    ' Readout
    For j = 0 To UBound(OutArr, 2)
        xStr = ""
        For i = 0 To UBound(OutArr, 1)
            xStr = xStr & OutArr(i, j)
        Next i
        Debug.Print xStr
    Next j
End Sub

Function GetPermutations(ByRef InArr() As Variant, ByRef OutArr() As Variant, S2 As String, Optional S1 As String, Optional xRow As Long)
    If IsMissing(S1) Then S1 = ""
    If IsMissing(xRow) Then xRow = 0

    If Len(S2) < 2 Then
        ' "S1 & S2" would be the character map for this iteration
        Call LoadArray(InArr, OutArr, S1 & S2, xRow)
        xRow = xRow + 1
    Else
        Dim i As Integer: For i = 1 To Len(S2)
            Call GetPermutations(InArr, OutArr, Left(S2, i - 1) + Right(S2, Len(S2) - i), S1 + Mid(S2, i, 1), xRow)
        Next i
    End If
End Function

Function LoadArray(ByRef InArr() As Variant, ByRef OutArr() As Variant, Order As String, xRow As Long)
    Dim i As Integer: For i = 1 To Len(Order)
        OutArr(i - 1, xRow) = InArr(Asc(Mid(Order, i, 1)) - 65)
    Next i
End Function

Function Fact(i As Integer) As Long
    Fact = 1: For j = 1 To i: Fact = Fact * j: Next j
End Function
```